# How to use Angular CDK Drag and Drop library to upload files

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have a custom angular file-upload component which I would like to use [Angular CDK drag&drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview). It looks nice, but when I try to implement it to handle a file upload (you drag a file into the dropzone) it doesn't seem to work and the browser opens the file in a new tab.

What I have right now looks like this:

```
<label cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="handleFileDrop($event)">
    <span>Drop file here</span>
    <input #fileInput type="file" multiple="false" (change)="addFiles(fileInput.files">
</label>
```

So my question is, can I do FileUploads with the Angular CDK Drag and Drop library, and if so, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, you can't.

Dragging / dropping a file triggers a different event (i.e. [DragEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent)) than dragging and dropping elements marked with the CDK `CdkDrag` directive.

So you'll have to refer to the good old `dragenter` / `dragleave` / `drop` events and manually handle the logic (i.e. add the file(s) from the dataTransfer property of the event on drop, probably change styling during dragenter / dragleave, etc.).